# Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException:

Tags: spring-boot

I have a problem, when creating spring boot application and trying to start it. I always get error message in eclipse:

```
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.net.MalformedURLException: Local host name unknown: java.net.UnknownHostException
```

I also tried to use spring-tool-suite but I have a same error message. Does anyone know what's the problem?

Comment: So, did you solve the problem? Mind posting the answer if you did?

Answer (score -1):

Ran into this trying to debug a Spring Boot project in Eclipse as well. I went and added a hosts entry in my /etc/hosts for the local IP and hostname you see in the console error. That seems to have cleared it up on my Linux dev machine.

On Windows I believe the entry goes into the C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file.